# Worklight Adapter Communication over UDP protocol to port 5556 possible?

Tags: udp, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Is it posible to communicate to a range of specific ports with the worklight adapters?

Someone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but in the adapter's XML file you can specify the protocol, domain and port in which the adapter is in using the  tag and the  tag.

More information on the adapter XML file here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_the_adapter_xml_file.html

Comment: Nope, he wants to specify a RANGE of port numbers for an adapter to use, which AFAIK is not possible, at least in the adapter XML. I do not know of another location that would allow that either, though.